# How to delete all webs and all there subwebs using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to delete all webs and subwebs like this,

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

Get-SPWebApplication https://portal.fruits.com   | Get-SPSite -Limit All  | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | where {$_.Url -Match "crates"}  | ForEach-Object  {

        Remove-SPWeb $_ -Confirm:$false
}
```

How to delete subwebs and there webs here ?

Comment: I think you can just Pipe everything into the Remove-SPWeb command. Are you getting any errors with what you listed above?

Comment: It looks like for you could be suitable just to delete the site collection. Or do you need to delete all subsites from certain level?

Comment: @luccio there's a filter applied near the end, so it's just some specific sub-sites

Comment: This will need a recursion. if a web has sub web underneath, it can't be deleted.

Comment: Add order by url length decreasing

Comment: As suggested by Nadeem Yousuf: do the recursion...start with the first site defined by URL and then check if web.AllWebs is not null/count > 0 and do recursion. Of course delete the web at the end of the function (after recursion on child webs)

Answer (score 1):

So as to not leave this unanswered, the PowerShell below should clean up all sites that match the "crates" filter you specified.

```
Get-SPWebApplication https://portal.fruits.com | Get-SPSite -Limit All  | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | where {$_.Url -Match "crates"} | Sort-Object { $_.Url.Length } -Descending | Remove-SPWeb
```

I tested here using -whatif and the sort order solved the recursion requirement that Yousuf mentioned.